# shiny app pool connection to Postgresql disappears when running from docker

Tags: r, postgresql, docker, shiny

I have some issues with deployment of shiny app with Postgresql Backend in Docker on Kubernetis Host. After the shiny app runs some time I get following message:

`Warning in postgresqlQuickSQL(conn, statement, ...) :   Could not create execute: SELECT 1`

The app does not work properly without docker reboot after this warning. I do not get any problems with my local version of the same app.

I do not quit understand where the problem comes from - is it the db settings, the problem in connection between DB and Docker or admin/user rights issues. In Shiny App I use dbPool to create connections to db and also close the pool on session end. I think that the pool object handles timeout in this case by its own.

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code you've attempted (including listing non-base R packages, and any errors/warnings received), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`), and intended output given that input. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.